# react-native check and prompt user to enable Network/GPS

Tags: react-native, gps, location

I am looking around on how to check if network or GPS are enabled on a device when my application starts. And if they are disabled prompt the user to enable it.

Is this posible in React-native?, and is there any class or tool that could help with this type of dialogs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I am going to start answering my own question.

For GPS:

there seems to be a sensible solution. IOS seems to natively request if there is a geolocation request. And for Android this is not natively supported but someone has created a module for that ( https://github.com/webyonet/react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box )

so in my action creator I added the next code:

```
if(Platform.OS === 'android')
LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({ 
                message: "<h2>Use Location?</h2> \
                            This app wants to change your device settings:<br/><br/>\
                            Use GPS for location<br/><br/>", 
                ok: "YES", 
                cancel: "NO" 
            }).then(() => { 
                locationTracking(dispatch, getState, geolocationSettings)
            })
```

For Network:
There is no native support for neither so i end up doing my own action creator to check.

```
export function networkCheck(){
  return (dispatch) => {
    const dispatchNetworkState = (isConnected) => dispatch({
      type: types.NETWORK_STATE,
      state: isConnected
    })
    const handle = () => NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(dispatchNetworkState)
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', handle);
  }
}
```

A little extra:

for GPS i added this to check if the user goes and disable GPS on the middle of the task.

```
export function locationCheck(geolocationSettings = {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000, distanceFilter:10}){
  return (dispatch) => {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        () => {
            dispatch({
                type: types.LOCATION_STATE,
                state: true
            })
        },
        () => {
            dispatch({
                type: types.LOCATION_STATE,
                state: false
            })
        },
        geolocationSettings)
  }
}
```

Comment: "IOS seems to natively request if there is a geolocation request" - it only seems to happen on the first request. on later requests they simply fail from the code and don't display any dialogue prompt. Tested on an iPhone SE with iOS 8 and the error message I get it "Location services disabled."

Comment: How do you prompt the user to enable network connection? This only checks the status right?

Comment: @HenningHall if you go through Kanekoti'c [npm package](https://github.com/webyonet/react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box ) then it will take you to location section in android settings

Comment: Is there a way to appear this box without any extra modules?

Answer (score 16):

For enabling location/gps on Android I can recommend this module: https://github.com/Richou/react-native-android-location-enabler

It is using the **standard Android dialog** for location:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to appear this box without any extra modules?

Comment: does this work with Android 10 because it does not comes in many devices. Anyone have any workAround???

Comment: It is throwing an error saying null is not an object in react-native 0.62

Comment: @amitpandya please check the issues from this project: https://github.com/Richou/react-native-android-location-enabler/issues

Comment: You will be facing issues with this lib if Google Play Services is not installed like newly distributed Huawei devices.

Comment: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeAndroidLocationEnabler.default.promptForEnableLocationIfNeeded')

Answer (score 0):

If you use any kind of package to get the user's location, most likely they will automatically ask for the user to enable the hardware part when you request it for the first time.

So, you can do something like this to show the prompt:

```
CheckForGPSEnablement() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        RNLocation.configure({
            distanceFilter: 100, // Meters
            desiredAccuracy: {
                ios: "best",
                android: "balancedPowerAccuracy",
            },
            // Android only
            androidProvider: "auto",
            interval: 5000, // Milliseconds
            fastestInterval: 10000, // Milliseconds
            maxWaitTime: 5000, // Milliseconds
            // iOS Only
            activityType: "other",
            allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates: false,
            headingFilter: 1, // Degrees
            headingOrientation: "portrait",
            pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically: false,
            showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: false,
        })
            .then(x => {
                console.log({ x })
                resolve(true)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log({ err })
                resolve(false)
            })
    })
}
```

In my case I've used [react-native-location](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-location).