# Device GPS configuration in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, gps, android-gps

I'm developing a `react-native` app and I want to check that if the GPS of device is on do something and if the device's GPS is off, tell the user and request him to turn it on. So my question is:

- How can I check that the GPS of device is on?
- How can I redirect the user to GPS setting page?

I want to do these without adding any new package to project.

Comment: please check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795968/react-native-check-and-promp-user-to-enable-network-gps

Comment: Thank you for comment but this answer is an external package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved. I should use the error code of the `getCurrentPosition` function. If error code equals 1, it means that the GPS of device is off.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        ...
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error.code === 1) {
          // gps is off
        }
        ...
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 10000},
    )
```

Comment: how did you find out that error.code === 1 indcates gps is off

Comment: @AbdulMateenShaikh This comment is for a long time ago and I can’t remember exactly but I think I got that by manual test.